# Half Laplace operator

Tags: operator-theory

I'm curious whether a half Laplacian (or square root of Laplacian) exists. More specifically, I'm looking for an $X:C^2(\Bbb R^n)\to C^2(\Bbb R^n)$ operator such that $$\forall f:XXf=\Delta f$$ I know that $\nabla^2=\Delta$, but $\nabla$ gives a vector-vector function, and I would like a vector-number just like my original $f$.

*Motivation:* Treating the $\nabla$ operator as a vector, I thought why not calculate $$\|\nabla\|=\sqrt{\langle\nabla;\nabla\rangle}=\sqrt\Delta=X$$ The next step could be creating a "normalized" gradient operator $\nabla^0=\frac\nabla{\|\nabla\|}$, i.e. finding a $\nabla^0$ operator such that $\nabla^0X=\nabla$. Whether this has any use in practice is up to future generations to decide. I would appreciate any comments on this crazy idea.

Comment: An approach that doesn't answer you question directly, but can give another idea. Try $Y[f] = \mathcal F^{-1}[|\xi|\mathcal F[f](\xi)]$. The analogy with Laplacian: $\mathcal F[\Delta f](\xi)=-|\xi|^2 \mathcal F[f](\xi)$.

Comment: The square root of the Laplacian is not so natural, since $\Delta$ is a negative operator. Usually one prefers to study the square root of $-\Delta$: the square root of the Laplacian then can be taken to be $i \sqrt{-\Delta}$. This operator can be defined via [functional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus).

Comment: Small quibble: $X$ cannot be $C^2\to C^2$. The Laplacian maps $C^2 \to C^0$! The best you can hope for is that $X:C^k \to C^{k-1}$ for all $k \geq 1$. The usual definitions work better with Sobolev spaces.

Comment: Lastly, if one is willing to look at objects other than purely scalar valued functions, your problem has been nicely solved by [Dirac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_operator) a long time ago. The Dirac operator acts on sections of a vector bundle, but the domain and codomain lives, morally speaking, in the same vector bundle, unlike the usual divergence and gradient where one of the domain/codomain is scalar functions and the other is vector valued.

Comment: Let me add a little more to these excellent comments.  The operator $\frac{\nabla}{\sqrt{-\Delta}}$ can be written as a vector of operators $(R_1,\dots,R_n)$.  These operators are called *Riesz transforms* in the literature.

Comment: There is nothing crazy about your ideas.  In the theory of PDE's and harmonic analysis they are used all the time, and are probably amongst some of the more important ideas in 20th Century mathematics.

Comment: @Willie Wong - There is no implication of onto with A: X\rightarrow B. So 'cannot' is not correct.

Comment: @T.A.E. in principle you are right. In practice: we are talking about the standard Laplacian here. Do I really have to write down for you a $C^2$ function whose Laplacian is not twice continuously differentiable?

Comment: If you work in a Sobolev space then there is a square root. There you can use the Fourier transform where the Laplacian is turned into multiplication, which has a nice square root. And, as someone else pointed out, you can factor by using matrices A, B, C such that AA=-I, BB=-I, CC=-I, AB+BA=0,AC+CA=0,BC+CB=0, which is what Dirac did. (He used one more to put time into it, too, and ended up discovering the positron.)

Comment: @Willie Wong - I'm sorry about that remark. Morning brain glitch.

Comment: This page expands on Stephen Montgomery-Smith's mention of the Riesz derivative, and comes about as close to working in a classical setting as you may be able to get. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

Comment: Appendix B.3.2 is of potential relevance: https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2011.00777.x